# Raspberry have DNS, but 100%packet loss

Tags: raspbian, networking

Today I moved my raspberry of place, it s connected to the same switch, same router, but different port.

I can ssh to it (so obviously, it connect at least to the switch), my PC is on the same switch and I m writing this on it, so the switch is connected to internet, my conclusion is that the problem must be on the raspberry...

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.34.167) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
44 packet transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 43005ms
```

I m as lost as the packet, it was working fine just yesterday, all I ve done is move it to connect the switch on a different port!

Running Raspbian 7.4, Firmware 3.10.25+, connected by ethernet.

Comment: what stops you from connecting it to the same port as before?

Comment: The Pi is a work project, I ve been moved from the place where it worked fine, I m supposed to make it work again at my new desktop...

Comment: does ´ping 8.8.8.8´ work?
does ´ping yourPC_IP´ work?

Comment: @LukasWiniwarter: `ping 8.8.8.8` doesn t work, but I can ping the router and my pc fine.

Comment: are you able to check if the router/switch prohibits internet access for the ethernet port you used, by e.g. connecting a laptop pc?

Comment: @LukasWiniwarter: The Pi and my PC are on the same switch, which is on the ethernet port. Firewalls allowed the pi to go throught it until, well, this morning, so it shoudn t be an issue.

Comment: just to rule out every last doubt.. are you able to go back to the place it was before and test it once more?

Comment: @LukasWiniwarter: Not until next week sadly, I ll edit when I ll have been able to test it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13988/discussion-between-lukas-winiwarter-and-drakasan)

Comment: My router sometimes blocks net traffic of devices for no reason. See if you can force a DHCP renewal.

Comment: @Fred: Already tried to reboot the PI (which is supposed to renew the DHCP if I understand).

Comment: Have you verified it's actually a different IP with the `ifconfig` command?

Comment: It s not a different IP. The office work with fixed IP.

Comment: Sounds like a routing issue. Can you include the output of the following commands: `ip addr`, `ip -4 route show`, `ip -6 route show`, `sudo iptables -L -v -n`, `sudo ip6tables -L -v -n`.